# Rust cloning HashMap<String, Object> without moving into closure

Tags: rust, hashmap, closures, borrow-checker, cloning

I am trying to make my own programming language in rust, and most features are done, so I thought I could add to the UnknownIdentifier error the ability to find the closest match to whatever the user wanted

However before I even got to finding the closest match I found out that cloning HashMap<String, Object> moves it into the closure

ErrorGenerator::error function:

```rs
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
mod ErrorGenerator {
    pub fn error(name: &str, explanation: &str, line: usize, col: usize, file: String, after_f: Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>) -> ! {
        eprintln!("\n[ERROR] {}, Line {:?}, Column {:?}", file, line, col);
        eprintln!("    {}: {}", name, explanation);
        after_f();
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

```rs
ErrorGenerator::error(
    "UnknownIdentifier",
    &format!("unknown identifier: `{}`, this identifier could not be found", tokenc.repr()),
    tokenc.line,
    tokenc.col,
    tokenc.file,
    Box::new(||{
        let mut hashc: Vec<String> = hashs.clone().into_keys().collect();
        hashc.sort();
    }),
);
```

This is the error it gives:

```
error[E0597]: `hashs` does not live long enough
    --> src/runtime/runtime.rs:960:70
     |
959  |                                       Box::new(||{
     |                                       -        -- value captured here
     |  _____________________________________|
     | |
960  | |                                         let mut hashc: Vec<String> = hashs.clone().into_keys().collect();
     | |                                                                      ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
961  | |                                         hashc.sort();
962  | |                                     }),
     | |______________________________________- cast requires that `hashs` is borrowed for `'static`
...
1203 |       }
     |       - `hashs` dropped here while still borrowed
```

The problem's solution is probably either:

- A way to borrow in 'static lifetime a mutable variable created in a method into a closure
  or
- A way to clone HashMap<String, Object> without moving it into the closure

You can find the full code in https://github.com/kaiserthe13th/tr-lang/tree/unknown-id-err-impl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that the compiler doesn't clone `hashs` then passes the clone to your callback; instead, it passes a reference to `hashs` to your callback and clones it *inside the callback*.

However, the callback is required to be `'static`, and if it holds a reference to the containing function it is not! So the compiler is complaining.

What you want is to clone the hashmap *before*, then pass *the clone* to the callback. Like:

```rust
ErrorGenerator::error(
    "UnknownIdentifier",
    &format!("unknown identifier: `{}`, this identifier could not be found", tokenc.repr()),
    tokenc.line,
    tokenc.col,
    tokenc.file,
    {
        let hashc = hashs.clone();
        Box::new(|| {
            let mut hashc: Vec<String> = hashc.into_keys().collect();
            hashc.sort();
        })
    },
);
```

If you'll do that, you'll also recognize that the closure needs to be `FnOnce()` since you're moving out of `hashc` (`.into_keys()`). So `after_f: Box<dyn FnOnce()>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the same but without FnOnce, because I am not familiar enough with closures I guess

Comment: I'll put you in the thanks section of the project

Comment: This answer looks good. A nitty thing is cloning HashMap will clone its keys, values and hasher. That might not be efficient if what you need is the clone of the keys. I think you can clone the keys directly, instead of the hashmap,  and move the cloned keys to the closure. With that, FnOnce will not be required.

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu Yes, you're right, but I perhaps the OP needs to perform more work with the hashmap so I just answered the question. If not, a better usage will be to do outside the closure `let hashc: Vec<String> = hashs.keys().cloned().collect();`.